# What's the best way to update my Wordpress theme to Elementor?

Tags: plugins, themes, updates, design

I currently have a Wordpress site that is completely built out. I want to rebuild the entire site using the elementor plugin. What is the best way to go about rebuilding the site without having to override any of current themes and pages until I am ready to make the redesign go live? I don't want to have to create a new Wordpress account and change the DNS, I want the same Wordpress account  because I paid for certain plugins that I do not want to lose

Comment: Welcome! This unfortunately isn't the right place to ask opinion-based questions like this :/ just not the right format for this site as there isn't one right answer that can be marked as "correct". Read more [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). A good place I'd recommend to start looking is at staging site plugins, or using a subdomain (staging.example.com) and then migrating your site over using something like the Duplicator plugin.

Comment: @Brandon, you mentioned a WordPress account - are you by chance using WordPress.com hosting rather than WordPress.org? This Stack helps with .org sites which are handled differently. If yours is on .com you should check .com's documentation or contact their support and they can help - it's a common question.